# TSQL Duplicate rows based on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm trying to achieve the following with tsql

What i have in my table looks like this

```
A B C 3
```

what i want to have is

```
A B C 1
A B C 1
A B C 1
```

to split it based on the quantity column 4..

Not sure what function to use.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could join with a number-table, then it's easy as:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM dbo.Numbers n
INNER JOIN Table1 t
  ON n.n <= t.Col4
ORDER by n.n
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c000c/3/0)</kbd>

As shown in the fiddle you can create the [number table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) in this way:

```
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(n)
-- WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
;
```